# how to write the transpose of an augumented matrix?

Tags: matrices

Suppose given k square matrices $A_1, A_2, ... , A_k$ then i wanted to know how to find the transpose of the augumented matrix $(A_1|A_2|...|A_k)?$ I am thinking that it must be  equals to $(A_1^T|A_2^T|...|A_k^T).$ Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is just: $$ \left( \begin{matrix}  A_1^T \\ \vdots \\ A_k^T \end{matrix} \right)$$ If each matrix is $n\times n$ then it has the size: $(nk) \times n$